# .NET 'Settings' not working on 64-bit (InvalidOperationException)

Tags: c#, .net, 64-bit, settings, save

I am building a C# .NET (VS2010) application but am having some trouble saving settings, (which work fine under 32bit Windows XP), under 64bit Windows 7.

I have a Settings.settings in the solution, with a settings test value named res112text in, set as type string at user scope, with 'Internal' as the access modifier setting.

Then the save command in

```
Properties.Settings.Default.res112text = "10002b";
try
{
   Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
}
catch (Exception e)
{
   MessageBox.Show(e.GetType().ToString() + " for " + e.Message.ToString());
}
```

when caught instantly brings up the error type:

```
System.InvalidOperationException
```

and for the exception message it says:

`Method failed with unexpected error code 3`

I am packing the .dll.config file in the setup installer and it installs into the Program Files directory fine.

Can anyone suggest what might be going wrong please?

Update: The full error is..

```
Error System.InvalidOperationException: Method failed with unexpected error 
code 3. 

at System.Security.AccessControl.NativeObjectSecurity.CreateInternal(
ResourceType resourceType, Boolean isContainer, String name, SafeHandle 
handle, AccessControlSections includeSections, Boolean createByName, 
ExceptionFromErrorCode exceptionFromErrorCode, Object exceptionContext)

at System.Security.AccessControl.FileSecurity..ctor(String fileName, 
AccessControlSections includeSections)

...

at System.Configuration.SettingsBase.Save()

at MyAddon.IEModule.ConfigSave()
```

Update: It appears there isn't a workaround when IE's Protected Mode is enabled, unless all users switch it off manually.

Comment: Wrong exception message, but yeah, having an Explorer addin creating files on anything other than isolated storage is a fail whale.  Name collisions are not impossible either.

Comment: What method would you use? I tried saving the settings in files and such but every thing I tried one system refused it.

Comment: Can anyone suggest a solution to the method I'm using please??

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problem is probably caused because of insufficient rights to save the file. Like Hans Passant suggested, you should take a look at Isolated storage: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.isolatedstorage.isolatedstoragefile.aspx

The purpose of isolated storage is to allow applications with limited rights to save data. The MSDN page contains a code sample that should get you up-and-running.

Comment: If Settings is a built in feature of Visual Studio then I can't understand why it wouldn't be a recommended method of storage?

Comment: It looks like IE's protection prevents it working. I will look into implementing Isolated storage instead, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I can use Save() method if there is no DLL "user.config" file, but I can't do the same when there is one already. So the workaround is probably to delete the "user.config" file manually (which is curiously working)

```
System.IO.File.Delete(System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.OpenExeConfiguration(System.Configuration.ConfigurationUserLevel.PerUserRoaming).FilePath);
```

and then use the Save() method to create a new "user.config" file.
Please let me know if there is a catch, but so far I haven't noticed any.